# R add mschart to Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Lovely day to you all!

I want to insert a mschart into an Rmd which I would like to knit to docx.
I have no idea how to insert the plot. For "normal" docx this works:

```
ms_linechart(data = mtcars, x = "vs", y = "mpg", group = "gear") -> chart
doc <- read_docx()
doc <- body_add_chart(doc, chart = chart, style = "centered")
print(doc, target = "example.docx")
```

Here's my code so far which is not working:

````
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Your Name"
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.cap = TRUE)
library(officedown)
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(mschart)
```

```{r}
body_add_chart(ms_linechart(data = mtcars, x = "vs", y = "mpg", group = "gear"))

```
````

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I e-mailed the developer and it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, which is not ideal, but that might be helpful for some:

In a chunk:

```
#Create plot object
my_plot <- 
data %>% 
  mschart::ms_scatterchart('x', 'y')

#Create a doc object using officer. Add chart.  
doc <- 
officer::read_docx() %>% 
body_add_chart(chart = my_plot)

#Save document to a folder
print(doc, target = here::here(path_results, "my_plot.docx"))

#Pour that document into the rmarkdown 
block_pour_docx(here::here(path_results, "my_plot.docx"))
```